# VBA for executing something based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet where I have input a formula in a particular column which gives me either a Yes or a No.  I want a code which will search that column for "Yes" and wherever it finds it - I should get the row number of all those cells

Comment: Please attach screenshot or provide sample data to let us know how your excel looks like.

Comment: Hello Santosh and welcome to [SO]! Please post the code you already have so we can help you where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Sub marine()
    For Each r In Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        If r.Value = "Yes" Then
            msg = msg & vbCrLf & r.Row
        End If
    Next r
    MsgBox "Yes found in rows " & msg
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for answering his question without exactly knowing what he wants in a way that will always work. And I love how you did that submarine joke there.